# Where is the source of fileuploader.swf?

Tags: dojo

I want to read the source of dojox/form/resources/fileuploader.swf.Where can I get the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The README file in dojox/form says :
"dojo.form.FileUploader depends on dojox.embed, and uses Flash movies created
    in the deft project using Flex OSS 3.  You do not need any of the deft code; 
    compiled movies are included with dojox.form in the resources folder.
    If you want to modify the actual movies, you can look in the deft project 
    (under the package deft.av)."

You will find that here : http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/browser/dojo/deft/trunk/deft/av

Comment: It has cost my long time for googling,and I forgot README.Thanks.